# Octomap in moveit

Tags: octomap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I  already can see octomap in rviz but the problem is the octomap is quite different from the real world kinect sees. I don't know why. Do I need to adjust any parameter for configuration file?
Besides, the refresh rate is quite low. Anybody know how to change refresh rate of octomap?
Thanks for any suggestion.
[image: image description]
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270619/octomap-in-moveit/) by [Oh233](https://answers.ros.org/users/30294/oh233/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2017-09-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Octomap updates are pretty expensive CPU-wise, so you might be limited by that. You can check CPU consumption using the `top` command line utility. Also note that you should be using the Depth Image Occupancy Map Updater (not the PointCloud Occupany Map Updater) with RGBD-type cameras as it tends to provide better performance (see [here](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/pr2_moveit_tutorials/html/planning/src/doc/perception_configuration.html)).

Regarding the shape of the octomap it would be helpful if you could post/link a screenshot (by editing your question). It should be noted that RGBD-cameras generate fairly noisy data (esp. at longer ranges), so deviations from how the real world looks can be expected.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2017-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Oh233](https://answers.ros.org/users/30294/oh233/) on 2017-09-11**:
Hi Kihlbrecher,
I attached the screenshot. In the real world, there should be a desk in left front of the arm. But in the octmap, I don't understand why there is a big block with no shape. Even I put something on the desk, it shouldn't be like that. It is too inaccurate.
Thanks

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2017-09-13**:
It's kind of hard to make out how the exact setup looks like. One obvious thing to do would be using the Camera display in rviz and using it to reproject the octomap into the camera image to check it for consistency.

**Comment by [Oh233](https://answers.ros.org/users/30294/oh233/) on 2017-09-14**:
Now my another problem is I want to use depth image from meta glass which runs on window system. I already transited data image from window to linux and published it on a topic. But even I let moveit to subscribe that topic, it can't form octomap. Is that because I need to modify type of depth image

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2017-10-05**:
You have to make sure that the proper frames and camera_info are published for that image.